# Method appends message the same number of times as what's in the corresponding array

Tags: java, arraylist, textarea, textfield

I have an array of answers that get's checked during a method. The usersinout then get's checked to see if it matches anything from the array of answers, if it does fine. However when it does, I call a method to wipe the userInput and display not a valid input, however it display "not a valid input" dependent on the number of answers in the array. Here's what I mean:

```
Type go in the box and hit enter!

Not a valid input

go

You reach a crossroads and don't know which way to go.

What do you do?

Not a valid input

Not a valid input

Not a valid input

Not a valid input

Not a valid input
```

Before I typed "go" I typed "g" on it's own and it returned "Not a valid input" as the only answer in the array for that section is "go". However on the next section you can see it returns "not a valid input" multiple times as there are 5 correct answers in the array corresponding to that section. How can I get it to return only once each and every time regardless of the number of answers in the array?

The code can be found on GitHub here for the entire game:

https://github.com/addrum/TextGame/

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Did you just try to debug your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this method:

```
public void check(String userInput) {
    boolean gotItRight= false;
    ArrayList<String> levelAnswers = answers.getAnswersForLevel(currentLevel);
    for (String answer : levelAnswers) {
        if (userInput.toLowerCase().equals(answer)) {
            messageDisplay.append("\n \n" + userInput + "\n");
            commandInput.setText("");
            messageDisplay.append("\n" + messages.getNextMessage());
            currentLevel++;
            getCurrentLevel();
            gotItRight= true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!gotItRight) {
        notValid();
    }
}
```

Why is it happening?

Well, you iterate over five answers for level one in this line: `for (String answer : levelAnswers)` and every time you evaluate that the answer does not match you display that the answer is wrong. For example, if the answer was right but for the last (5th option) you would get four times that is wrong, and at the end that it is right.

Also, you could do something like this to **avoid the for loop**:

```
public void check(String userInput) {
    boolean gotItRight= false;
    ArrayList<String> levelAnswers = answers.getAnswersForLevel(currentLevel);

    if (levelAnswers.contains(userInput.toLowerCase()) {
        messageDisplay.append("\n \n" + userInput + "\n");
        commandInput.setText("");
        messageDisplay.append("\n" + messages.getNextMessage());
        currentLevel++;
        getCurrentLevel();
        gotItRight= true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great thanks! Is it better to use the for loop or the if? Both works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a very brief look at your code. Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this method seem wrong to me.

```
public void check(String userInput)
```

I think that better way to do this is to use the contains method of the List. The result code would be like this.

```
// Assume that the prepared answers are in lower case
ArrayList<String> levelAnswers = answers.getAnswersForLevel(currentLevel);
if (levelAnswers.contains(userInput.toLowerCase()))
{ /* Found */ }
else
{ /* Not found */ }
```

Comment: Someone already have me a similar solution but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You are printing it out every time you check an answer, because notValid is being called in the for loop. Call it outside of the for loop and use a flag to indicate whether the answer was valid or not.

Here is the relevant code, you can see notValid is being called in the for loop.

```
public void check(String userInput) {
    ArrayList<String> levelAnswers = answers.getAnswersForLevel(currentLevel);
    for (String answer : levelAnswers) {
        if (userInput.toLowerCase().equals(answer)) {
            messageDisplay.append("\n \n" + userInput + "\n");
            commandInput.setText("");
            messageDisplay.append("\n" + messages.getNextMessage());
            currentLevel++;
            getCurrentLevel();
        } else {
            notValid();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's one possible solution, however I did not run it to check if it works properly.

```
boolean valid = true;
public void check(String userInput) {
    ArrayList<String> levelAnswers = answers.getAnswersForLevel(currentLevel);
    for (String answer : levelAnswers) {
        if (userInput.toLowerCase().equals(answer)) {
            messageDisplay.append("\n \n" + userInput + "\n");
            commandInput.setText("");
            messageDisplay.append("\n" + messages.getNextMessage());
            currentLevel++;
            getCurrentLevel();
                            valid = true;
                            return;

        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
    }
            if(!valid)
                 notValid();
            valid = true;
}
```